# Grammar.parse seems to loop forever and use 100% CPU

Tags: grammar, raku

*Reposted from [the #perl6 IRC channel, by jkramer, with permission](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2018-04-12#i_16038822)*

I'm playing with grammars and trying to parse an ini-style file but somehow Grammar.parse seems to loop forever and use 100% CPU. Any ideas what's wrong here?

```
grammar Format {
  token TOP {
    [
      <comment>*
      [
        <section>
        [ <line> | <comment> ]*
      ]*
    ]*
  }

  rule section {
    '[' <identifier> <subsection>? ']'
  }

  rule subsection {
    '"' <identifier> '"'
  }

  rule identifier {
    <[A..Za..z]> <[A..Za..z0..9_-]>+
  }

  rule comment {
    <[";]> .*? $$
  }

  rule line {
    <key> '=' <value>
  }

  rule key {
    <identifier>
  }

  rule value {
    .*? $$
  }
}

Format.parse('lol.conf'.IO.slurp)
```

Comment: Maybe you could also post the sample ini-file `lol.conf`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Token `TOP` has the `*` quantifier on a subregex that can parse an empty string (because both `<comment>` and the group that contains `<section>` have a `*` quantifier on their own).

If the inner subregex matches the empty string, it can do so infinitely many times without advancing the cursor. Currently, Perl 6 has no protection against this kind of error.

It looks to me like you could simplify your code to

```
token TOP {
  <comment>*
  [
    <section>
    [ <line> | <comment> ]*
  ]*
}
```

(there is no need for the outer group of `[...]*`, because the last `<comment>` also matches comments before sections.

Comment: Shouldn't you also use `token` instead of `rule` here? For example, the spaces in `rule comment {  <[";]> .*? $$  }` could gobble up newline characters before we reach the `$$` or am I wrong?

Comment: If vertical whitespace is significant, as suggested by use of `$$`, then it would be sensible to override `token ws { <!ww> \h* }` to match only horizontal whitespace. Much more on that, and two working grammars for INI files can be found in https://smile.amazon.com/Parsing-Perl-Regexes-Grammars-Recursive-ebook/dp/B0785L6WR6